# Is There a Way to Consolidate Facts?

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to turn this:

```
genre(blues).
gere(hiphop).
genre(rock).
```

Into something like this:

```
genre(blues;hiphop;rock).
```

*I know this does not work, but does something similar to this exist.

Comment: What is your reason for doing this? Are you trying to save time on typing? If so you can type like genre(rock). the ":- true." can be skipped in some compilers.

Comment: I know, the question lies within the parenthesis.

Comment: I'd just like to point out Answer Set Programming systems supports exactly that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot consolidate facts, but you can turn them into a simple rule, like this:

```
genre(X) :- member(X, [blues, hiphop, rock]).
```

`member/2` is a [built-in list predicate in SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29) to test list membership.

Answer (score 1):

This lets you apply a predicate across all of the elements of a list, and will succeed only if all applications succeed.

```
test_list( _, [] ).
test_list( F, [H|T] ) :- P =.. [F,H], P, test_list( F, T ).
```

Comment: By replacing `P =.. [F,H], P` by `call(F,H)` you have a more general version. This is usually called maplist: `maplist(F, L)` defined the same.

Comment: Thanks this is great, I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this syntax

```
genre(X) :- X=blues ; X=hiphop ; X=rock.
```

but personally I advice the member/2 way...